# Time and space complexity of SQL queries

Tags: sql

We want to find out all the employees and their hire date's such that their hire_date was greater than the hire date of employee named 'Davies' How do the two quesries compare to each other in terms of time and space complexity?

```
SELECT e.last_name, e.hire_date 
FROM employees e 
JOIN employees davies ON (davies.last_name = 'Davies') 
WHERE davies.hire_date < e.hire_date; 

SELECT e.last_name, e.hire_date 
FROM employees e 
JOIN employees davies ON (davies.hire_date < e.hire_date) 
WHERE davies.last_name = 'Davies';
```

Comment: Can you not run them and compare? We don't have access to your database....

Comment: It depends on indexes of course. Can we assume that there will be appropriate indexes for both queries?

Comment: Under most good optimizers, they'll be identical, since the second condition will get evaluated at the same time the first one is (because the statements are semantically equivalent).  You should be putting both conditions in the `ON` statement, anyways.

Comment: Take your query, let EXPLAIN explain how much records mysql needs to scan. Set INDEXES or change or extend them and run EXPLAIN and so on

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for this

```
SELECT e.last_name, e.hire_date 
FROM employees e 
WHERE e.hire_date > (SELECT TOP (1) hire_date FROM employees WHERE last_name = 'Davies')
```